# import an angular 5 module with rxjs into an angular 8 app

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm trying to import a module made in Angular 5 into an Angular 8 project.

When trying to serve it over, I have a bunch of errors:

```
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx2048/node_modules/@angular/core/esm2015/core.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/Observable' in 'C:\Users\JB\Dropbox\dev\battle2048\node_modules\ngx2048\node_modules\@angular\core\esm2015'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx2048/node_modules/@angular/core/esm2015/core.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/Subject' in 'C:\Users\JB\Dropbox\dev\battle2048\node_modules\ngx2048\node_modules\@angular\core\esm2015'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx2048/node_modules/@angular/core/esm2015/core.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/Subscription' in 'C:\Users\JB\Dropbox\dev\battle2048\node_modules\ngx2048\node_modules\@angular\core\esm2015'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx2048/node_modules/@angular/forms/esm2015/forms.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/observable/forkJoin' in 'C:\Users\JB\Dropbox\dev\battle2048\node_modules\ngx2048\node_modules\@angular\forms\esm2015'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx2048/node_modules/@angular/forms/esm2015/forms.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/observable/fromPromise' in 'C:\Users\JB\Dropbox\dev\battle2048\node_modules\ngx2048\node_modules\@angular\forms\esm2015'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx2048/node_modules/@angular/core/esm2015/core.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/observable/merge' in 'C:\Users\JB\Dropbox\dev\battle2048\node_modules\ngx2048\node_modules\@angular\core\esm2015'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx2048/node_modules/@angular/forms/esm2015/forms.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/operator/map' in 'C:\Users\JB\Dropbox\dev\battle2048\node_modules\ngx2048\node_modules\@angular\forms\esm2015'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx2048/node_modules/@angular/core/esm2015/core.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/operator/share' in 'C:\Users\JB\Dropbox\dev\battle2048\node_modules\ngx2048\node_modules\@angular\core\esm2015'
```

So it looks like a conflict of some sort? Do I have to fork the older module to migrate it to angular 8 as well?

Comment: you need to update rxjs operators in this specific module.. read migration docs of rxjs 5 to rxjs 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must check [Angular Update Guide](https://update.angular.io/),

If you look Angular 5 to 8 https://update.angular.io/#5.0:8.0, you can see

**After the Update** step ;

For lazy loaded modules via the router, importing via string is deprecated. `ng update` will take care of this automatically. The new syntax leverages the ecosystem wide support for `import` rather than our custom rewrites. Your loadChildren route configs should be changed from a string such as `loadChildren: './admin/admin.module#AdminModule'` to an import statement such as

```
loadChildren: () => import('./admin/admin.module').then(m => m.AdminModule).
```

**And Also :**

Remove deprecated RxJS 6 features using rxjs-tslint auto update rules

For most applications this will mean running the following two commands:

```
npm install -g rxjs-tslint
rxjs-5-to-6-migrate -p src/tsconfig.app.json
```

Comment: If you need something fast and dirty in the meantime, for the RxJS stuff you can add the `rxjs-compat` package to the project. But yeah, it's fast and dirty ^^

Answer (score 1):

In angular 6+ rxjs was added to the Angular framework so now you dont need to install the library is now included.

You need to change all the reference of the imports to use:

```
import { Observable, of} from 'rxjs';
```

after that any operational function like map, take, mergeMap etc, Should be added to this import and you will need to use .pipe(function, function, function) tu use any kind of operational funcction.

```
import { take, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Example:

```
of(inpututval).pipe(
  map(res=> res//todo something with the value),
  take(1) 
).subscribe(res => {console.log(res)});
```

The static reference to Observable is not necesary now so you can use directly the functionsli the function `of` in the prev example.